# Information on this Improper Integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I was working with integrals of the form
$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{k}(x) (1-2x)}{x^2 (x-1)^2}dx$$
And started toying around with it in Wolfram alpha, and noticed that ever $k$ I plugged in, Wolfram had an answer. But when leaving it as $k$ , it says there is no answer in any standard functions. I find that curious because it must be get the previous answers from somewhere? Is there in fact a closed form for this when $k$ is a natural number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with other CAS and faced the same situation as you did; apparently, there is no general formula.

However, if we expand as Taylor series,we can notice that 
$$\frac{1-2 x}{x^2(x-1)^2 }=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac n {x^{n+1}}$$ and then 
$$\int \frac {n\log^k(x)} {x^{n+1}}\,dx=-n^{-k} \Gamma (k+1,n \log (x))$$
$$\int_2^\infty \frac {n\log^k(x)} {x^{n+1}}\,dx=n^{-k} \,\Gamma (k+1,n \log (2))$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.
$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{k}(x) (1-2x)}{x^2 (x-1)^2}\,dx=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-k} \,\Gamma (k+1,n \log (2))$$

**Edit**

From a numerical point of view, the summation seems to converge quite fast. Let us consider the partial sum
$$S_p=-\sum_{n=2}^p n^{-k} \,\Gamma (k+1,n \log (2))$$ For $k=10$, we should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 2 & -3543.749089 \\
 3 & -3605.202406 \\
 4 & -3608.662579 \\
 5 & -3609.033817 \\
 6 & -3609.093604 \\
 7 & -3609.106306 \\
 8 & -3609.109596 \\
 9 & -3609.110581 \\
 10 & -3609.110910 \\
 11 & -3609.111029 \\
 12 & -3609.111075 \\
 13 & -3609.111094 \\
 14 & -3609.111101 \\
 15 & -3609.111105 \\
 16 & -3609.111106 \\
 17 & -3609.111107 \\
 18 & -3609.111107 \\
 19 & -3609.111107 \\
 20 & -3609.111108
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: It's so odd that there appears to be no general formula, yet it has a formula once you give $k$ a value? Is there one if we restrict $k$ to be a natural number? Perhaps these systems are considering it for any real $k$, and for that, perhaps there's no formula. Because surly it's doing these somehow.

Comment: @RyanGoulden. I did not find anything else. Numerically, the summations seem to converge quite fast. I add an example in my answer.